# How to run a specific dag first in airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm using apache airflow (2.3.1) to load data into a database. I have more than 150 dags, I need to run some of them first, how can I do this?
The initialization of the work of the dags occurs at 3 am and the dags start to run randomly, standing in a queue.

I read about priority_weight and weight_rule, but this is only used for tasks, not for dag in general.

As I said, the dag queue is built randomly, and I would like to control it and hard-code which dag should be executed first.

Comment: Upgrade to Airflow 2.4 and use Dataset dependency feature. Dags will be scheduled only when data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ExternalTaskSensor` to define cross-DAG dependencies.

In particular it allows you to wait for an external (= *on a different DAG*) task or DAG to complete before proceeding. You can configure the `dag_id` and `task_id` to wait for and a time-delta for the `execution_date` (by default, it expects that the external DAG run has the same execution date as the current).

Full details and possible configurations are available in the official documentation: [Cross-DAG Dependencies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/external_task_sensor.html).

---

### Example usage

#### Task to be executed first

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id = 'first_dag',
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval = '0 0 * * *'
) as first_dag:
    first_task = DummyOperator(task_id = 'first_task')
```

#### Task to be executed later

```py
with DAG(
    dag_id = 'second_dag',
    start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    schedule = '0 0 * * *'
) as second_dag:
    first_task_sensor = ExternalTaskSensor(
        task_id = 'first_task_sensor',
        external_dag_id = 'first_dag',
        external_task_id = 'first_task',
        timeout = 600,
        allowed_states = ['success'],
        failed_states = ['failed', 'skipped'],
        mode = 'reschedule'
    )

    second_task = DummyOperator(task_id = 'second_task')

    first_task_sensor >> second_task
```